# ORM in odoo framework

Tags: python, odoo

How to change the below sql query to ODOO orm

`select max(dnddate) from ink where id = 23 and type= 'h' and kar not in ("5") group by customer;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create your query using Odoo ORM, we should use the read_group function.

```py
inks = self.env['ink'].read_group([
            ('id', '=', 23),
            ('type', '=', 'h'),
            ('kar', 'not in', ("5"))], ['dnddate:max'], ['customer'])
```

Read about Model.read_group()

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#search-read

Comment: I think that the link should point to `read_group`.